# SQL Server: put select result in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i do for example:

```
select * from test
```

This will produce a result with all columns and rows of table test. It is possible to assign this result as "text" in one variable?

Thanks

Comment: you wud you need that all as text??

Comment: what is the type of that variable?? is that table variable??

Comment: Yes i want the complete result as text (the table headers could be out). The type is someone that supports text. For exemple: Declare @result nvarchar(500)

Comment: can you use text in xml format?

Comment: Something else.. I just want to have the query result as text :)

Comment: ok. what format you want to use: json, delimetered or other?

Comment: Why do you need this, I suspect there is a better solution as I have never heard of anyone needing what you described and it would not be a simple or easy task to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you asked for

```
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Xml xml = (select * from master..spt_values FOR XML PATH)
SELECT @Result = CAST(@Xml.query('string(.)') as nvarchar(max))
PRINT @Result
```

I suspect that you probably want some column/row delimiters in there though.

I'm not sure whether this could be altered to do this. My XML skills are a bit lacking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to cast all columns as nvarchar with concatinating it.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the fields you want (or all of them) into a varchar(max) or similiar.